# How can I tag just one Sentry event?

Tags: java, sentry

I want to report Sentry event with some specified tag, however I do not want to include this tag in future events.

With the following code, I'm adding a tag and reporting event:

```
Sentry.getContext().addTag("my_tag", "yes");
Sentry.capture("event happened");
```

Then, after a while, another event occurs:

```
Sentry.capture("another event happened"); // tag is included, but I don't want it
```

I've tried removing tag by `Sentry.clearContext()` but it clears all information, including breadcrumbs.

I've also tried `Sentry.getContext().getTags().remove("my_tag");` but, since tags are keept in `UnmodifiableMap`, this operation just throws an exception.

Comment: This is definitely an oversight in the current implementation. I (wrongly) assumed users would want tags to be set for the entire life of the context. I've created an issue here, and I think maybe the best current course of action is to add a `removeTag` method, any thoughts?: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/496

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of `sentry-java` 1.5.2 (just released to fix this) you can use new methods on the `Context` to clean up after temporary tags/extra data:

```
Sentry.getContext().removeTag("my_tag");
Sentry.getContext().clearTags();

Sentry.getContext().removeExtra("my_extra");
Sentry.getContext().clearExtra();
```